# How to get execution time on mongoDb with Dart?

Tags: mongodb, dart

How can I get the execution time of mongodb queries in Dart?

I am using https://github.com/mongo-dart/mongo_dart

Comment: I am trying to use this code:     var res = await db.queryMessage(new mongo.DbCommand(db, 'system.profile', mongo.MongoQueryMessage.OPTS_NONE, 0, -1, {
  'profile': 2
 }, null));     Do some find then this find:     var col = db.collection('system.profile');

  print('profiling...');
  await col.find().forEach((i) => print(i));     But it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to call `setProfilingLevel` (copying what is done for drop()). Note that it is a system command

```
DbCommand createSetProfilingLevelCommand(int level) {
  return new DbCommand(
      db,
      DbCommand.SYSTEM_COMMAND_COLLECTION,
      MongoQueryMessage.OPTS_NO_CURSOR_TIMEOUT,
      0,
      -1,
      {'profile':level},
      null);
}
print(await db.executeDbCommand(createSetProfilingLevelCommand(2)));
```

It should display something like that

```
{was: 0, slowms: 100, ok: 1.0}
```

Querying the collection is the same that you did (assuming you know how to use it!)

```
var coll = db.collection(DbCommand.SYSTEM_PROFILE_COLLECTION);
List list = await coll.find().toList();
for (var item in list) {
  print(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could record the time it takes for your code calling mongo_dart to execute with a `StopWatch`

```
var stopwatch = new StopWatch();
stopwatch.start();

await executeMyQuery();

print(stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: I assumed he's looking for something like https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: ah, sorry, I don't know about that.